# Saving and reading Picker values from SQLite - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like you to help me solve a problem that I can not deal with.

In my Xamarin.Forms application, the user can add to the SQLite database:

```
public class Car
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int PickerValue { get; set; }
    }
```

PickerValue is of type INT because I think that the selected value of the picker gives the index INT value. Am I wrong?

The user adds item using:

```
<Editor Placeholder="Enter name" Text="{Binding Text}" />
<Picker x:Name="myPicker" Title="Value:">
            <Picker.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>value 1</x:String>
                    <x:String>value 2</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </Picker.ItemsSource>
        </Picker>
```

On another page, items are displayed using ListView:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
<Label Text="{Binding PickerValue}"/>
```

When I select an item on the ListView - the edit page opens for me - the same page in which I added new products (code above) with filled fields from the database. I can edit them there.

I would like to be able to save the selected Picker value to SQLite, and on another page I can display it (or index of the selected value). Can someone help me how to make such a binding?

If it is possible - I would like to do it in XAML.

I made the project based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Answer (score 2):

Here is my running GIF.

[image]
You can directly set this picker.

Firstly, I add a property in the model, here is add a Gender property.

```
   public class Note
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public  string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Before you insert the data to your database, you should set this property like this code.You should convert the `myPicker.SelectedItem;` to `string`

```
 async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var note = (Note)BindingContext;
        note.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
        note.Gender = (string)myPicker.SelectedItem;
        await App.Database.SaveNoteAsync(note);
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

In the other page, we just binding the Gender property, like this code.

```
  <ListView x:Name="listView"
          Margin="20"
          ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
             <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Text}"></Label>

                <Label Text="{Binding Gender}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>

            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my demo.

https://github.com/851265601/databaseDemo

**Update**
There is GIF about change the text of the edit page, it works normally.
[image]

I just add the SelectedItem of picker,

```
   <Picker x:Name="myPicker" Title="Value:" SelectedItem="{Binding Gender}">
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>female</x:String>
                <x:String>male</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
    </Picker>
```

I update again for my project.
https://github.com/851265601/Datademo3/blob/master/Datademo2/Notes/App.xaml.cs

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It works very well. Unfortunately, I have one problem.  Inserting PickerValue into SQLite works ok, displaying the inserted Items on the ListView also works.However, when I click Item on ListView and go to EditPage (the same in which I added new Items) - each change and re-save(
49/5000
even when I change nothing and click save)  -> "Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.". Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @erbeen Is this issue occured in your project or my project? If it is occured in my project, I have update my anwer, check this function, it works normally, You also could change another name of this database, before you debug it. If this issue was occured in your project, You did not post your related code, I do not know which line will cause this issue, Please mark this thread(because this thread is related to Saving and reading Picker values from SQLite, it was solved), then open a new thread, post your related code, then we can toubleshot this new issue.

Comment: Is it possible from here?`async void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentSelection != null)
    {
        // Navigate to the NoteEntryPage, passing the ID as a query parameter.
        Note note = (Note)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NoteEntryPage)}?{nameof(NoteEntryPage.ItemId)}={note.ID.ToString()}");
    }
}  `