# Picker value saving to SQLite

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am having an issue with my picker. I followed this post [Saving and reading Picker values from SQLite - Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989126/saving-and-reading-picker-values-from-sqlite-xamarin-forms)

and i am getting "Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

This is my model

```
 public class AdLogEntry
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SellerName { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        //public ImageSource ImageName { get; set; }
        public byte[] OriginalImage { get; set; }
        public string Info { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string AnimalCategory { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime LoadedDate { get; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DatePicker GetDatePicker { get;  }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }

this is my code

private async void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await SaveAdLog();

        }
        //TODO IsNullOR for all
        //TODO Marks for required fields
        private async Task SaveAdLog()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NameEntry.Text) || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PriceEntry.Text) || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LocationEntry.Text)  )))
            {
                AdLogEntry adLogEntry = new AdLogEntry
                {
                    Location = LocationEntry.Text,
                    Price = PriceEntry.Text,
                    Name = NameEntry.Text,

                    Section = (string)SectionPicker.SelectedItem,
                    AnimalCategory = (string)CategoryPicker.SelectedItem,

                };
                _adService.CreateAddLogEntry(adLogEntry);
                await DisplayAlert(LabelCZ.AlertThankYou, LabelCZ.AlertSpace, LabelCZ.AlertOk);
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert(LabelCZ.AlertRequired, LabelCZ.AlertRequiredPlease, LabelCZ.AlertOk);
            };

        }


<Grid Grid.Row="0" RowSpacing="12">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Entry  x:Name="NameEntry" Placeholder ="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.LabelWhatAreYouSelling}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <Picker x:Name="SectionPicker"  Grid.Row="2"  Title="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.LabelSection}" ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding SectionName}" SelectedItem="{Binding Section}"/>
                                    <Picker x:Name="CategoryPicker" Grid.Row="3"  Title="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.LabelCategory}"  ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalCategories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding AnimalKind}" SelectedItem="{Binding AnimalCategory}"/>
                                    <Picker x:Name="PetsCategoryPicker" Grid.Row="4" Title="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.LabelPetsCategory}" ItemsSource="{Binding CatBreeds}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding CatBreedKind}" />
                                <Entry  x:Name="PriceEntry" Grid.Row="5" Placeholder ="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.LabelPrice}" FontSize="{ StaticResource SubTitleSize }"/>
                                <Entry  x:Name="LocationEntry" Grid.Row="6" Placeholder= "{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.LabelLocation}" FontSize="{ StaticResource SubTitleSize }" />
                                <Entry x:Name="PickUpDate" Grid.Row="7" Placeholder ="{x:Static resources:LabelCZ.LabelPickUPDay}" FontSize="{ StaticResource SubTitleSize }"/>


                            </Grid>
```

Maybe you guys can see some mistake?

Comment: this is the **exact same** problem you were having before.  You are trying to create a `DatePicker` column in your DB and SQLite has no idea what that is.  SQLite can only work with primitive types like int, string, DateTime, etc.

Comment: That is not the same picker, I am not using the date pciker yet. But thank you for answer I will make sure i sort that out.

Comment: These pickers are strings Section and Animal Category

Comment: Jason is talking about ` public **DatePicker** GetDatePicker { get;  } ` you should consider changing this to string

Comment: @ Leo Zhu - MSFT  Hi, it works for now, thank you. If you add it as answr i can mark it>]

Comment: @kon ok,i will delete the comment then,post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code above,i test your codes (just replace the Piker ItemSource to a fixed string array),it works,try to check your XF version,update and make sure the version is the same both in PCL project and android project or ios project